# ActiveRecord: find_by oblivious to custom getter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

ActiveRecord's `find_by` method seems to be oblivious to custom getters. That is, `find_by` seems to look at values actually stored in the database and not at what the getters return. Example:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("sqlite3::memory:")

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table(:users) { |t| t.string "name" }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name; self["name"] || "default" end
end

User.create({ "name" => "foo" })
User.create()

p User.find_by("name" => "foo")
p User.find_by("name" => "default")
p User.last.name
```

This prints:

```
#<User id: 1, name: "foo">
nil
"default"
```

I would have expected the second line not to be `nil`, but instead to show the second record added. What I am seeing may be the expected behavior of `find_by` (I don't know). However, what method could I use instead of `find_by`, which will use the value returned by the getters?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord is an interface to a *database* - all queries are converted to SQL. `User.find_by("name" => "foo")` executes `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'foo'`, then wraps results in a Ruby `User` object.

Your database is not aware of getters. To use a getter, you have to have a Ruby object first - which means you would need to retrieve *all* objects from your table, then use `.select` to filter the results in Ruby.

Comment: I see. What may be confusing, so I point it out here: *validation* does indeed seem to happen based on the values returned by the getters. If I add `validates "name", presence: true`, then `User.create().valid?` will still be true; it becomes false when I remove the custom getter.

Comment: Well, yes. `valid?` is a Ruby function, operating on a Ruby object, without touching SQL. `find` is just a bit of magic to translate your Ruby requests to SQL ones, and SQL results to Ruby ones - the search itself happens outside Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Amandan answer.

If you want to have defaults that are used by ActiveRecord finders, you need to set a default value on DB column:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table(:users) { |t| t.string "name", default: 'default' }
end
```

Comment: Thanks. In my real application, the situation is more complicated. The "default" value depends on `id`, say it should be `"default#{id}"`. Can you give an example how to do this properly?

Comment: In this case I'd suggest to find by id and `null` `name` value and then use app-level default (getter) - `User.where(id: id, name: nil)`. Or to set defualts in setters, similarly to a technique described here: https://blog.arkency.com/2016/01/drop-this-before-validation-and-use-method/